# Regex to replace = after href attribute in a tags in java

Tags: java, html, regex

i made a regex to replace "=" after "href" in "a" tags:

```
output.replaceAll("(<a.*)href=(.*>)", "$1href" + replacemantstring+ "$2");
```

The problem ist that it only replaces the last occurence of "=" after href ...

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide sample input with expected output?

Comment: You need to provide an input and expected output. Can't understand what exactly you want. The regex you posted doesn't replace anything.

Comment: Too many people answer without reading neither the question nor the tags... 3 answers over 4 are javascript answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your wildcards from *greedy* `.*` to *non-greedy* `.*?`. This will make your regex stop att the first `href=` match, and therefore match the following occurences too.

Comment: @Ωmega: With such a vaguely formulated question you are bound to find input that breaks it. Apparently my answer solved OPs problem, since he accepted it, so I don't really see the point in trying to find corner cases.

Comment: @Keppil For completeness, correctness, usability, and awareness.

Comment: @DaveNewton: The first two criteria demand a more specific and clear question. As for correctness, I believe I provided it. As for awareness, I don't think it applies here. With such a vague question, there is a near infinite amount of additional information that you can provide, and I'd rather just give a short answer to the specific problem.

Comment: You asked, I answered. I don't see how awareness of this specific weakness "doesn't apply", but perhaps you have a less-stringent view of what people should think about than I do. I'd rather people were aware of issues rather than ignore them--YMMV. For such an easy issue/solution, can't imagine why it wouldn't be better to just fix the potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace link in `href` paramenter with `newURL`, then use

```
output.replaceAll("(?i)(<a[^>]*?\\shref\\s*=)(['"]).*?\\2", "$1$2" + newURL + "$2");
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to replace just `=` behind `href` in `<a>` tag, then use

```
output.replaceAll("(?i)(<a[^>]*?\\shref\\s*)=", "$1" + replacement);
```

Comment: is this more efficient compared to the solution: (<a.*?)href=(.*?>) ?

Comment: yes, and when i do something like `output = output.replaceAll("(<a.*?)href=(.*?>)", "$1href"+ "#" +"$2");` for `<a href="abc!" style="dfg!">asd</a>` the output is as i want: `<a href#"abc!" style="dfg!">asd</a>`

Comment: Thats the first sentence of my question: "i made a regex to replace all "=" after "href" in "a" tags". Sorry if it was unclear, and thanks for your work :)

Comment: @NickRussler - Strange and not constructive task, as such `<a>` tag will be invalid after such replacement. My answer above is for link replacement. Good luck.